# Switched from Webpack to Vite and getting a build error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, vite

I recently switched our project from Webpack to Vite.

When I run `microbundle --tsconfig tsconfig.mb.json --sourcemap -f modern`

I get the following error:

```bash
Failed to resolve the module https://external-site.com/library.js imported by src/helpers/importLibrary.ts
Is the module installed? Note:
 ↳ to inline a module into your bundle, install it to "devDependencies".
 ↳ to depend on a module via import/require, install it to "dependencies".
Failed to resolve the module https://external-site.com/library.js imported by src/helpers/importLibrary.ts
Is the module installed? Note:
 ↳ to inline a module into your bundle, install it to "devDependencies".
 ↳ to depend on a module via import/require, install it to "dependencies".
```

Any idea how to fix this? Also, this isn't failing our build and this seems to be just a warning, but we would like to suppress this if possible. With Webpack we added in:

```js
/* webpackIgnore: true */
/* webpackMode: "lazy" */
```

Here is the import file:

```js
/* eslint-disable import/no-unresolved, import/extensions */
const importLibrary = async (): Promise<Library> => {
    return import(
      /* webpackIgnore: true */
      /* webpackMode: "lazy" */
      'https://external-site.com/library.js'
    )
}
/* eslint-enable */

export default importLibrary
```

We tried something creating an external file `./library` with the import in `helpers/importLibrary` then importing it like:

```js
const importLibrary = async (): Promise<Library> => {
   Promise.resolve(import('./library')).then({default: library}) => return library)
}
```

Which fixed in our module, but when the module was imported to other projects it failed.